# Yum repos for PyQt 4.7 above

Tags: repository, centos, yum

Can any one suggest some `yum repositories` for `PyQt-4.7` or above in `CentOS 6.0 i586.`? I tried installing it mannualy, but WebKit is making problem..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about that specific version.  But these are usually a good place to start:

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL
http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge